# Components not showing for ngIf

Tags: angular

I created a sample app in Angular 5. I have two components called **app-parent** and **app-child** and have a sample text in each. I have a variable in my App component and I need to show above components each at a time triggered by the value of variable.

This is the code.

App.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  val:string;
}
```

App.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="!val; then r; else s">
    <ng-template #r>
        <app-parent></app-parent>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #s>
        <app-child></app-child>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

I expect to `<app-parent>` be appeared, but in the result, nothing is appearing. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zafvpx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
should do what you want.

Put your condition in an ng-container:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="val == 'r' && val.length > 0; then r; else s" ></ng-container>
```

Note that **else s** will be always visible, when the condition is not fullfilled. If you don't want to go wich the then-else approach, I would place the *ngIf In the tags of the components to handle the visibility like:

```
<app-parent *ngIf="val == 'r'"></app-parent>
<app-child *ngIf="val == 's'></app-child>
```